# How get numeric between two character with regex java?

Tags: java, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy, boost-regex

**I have the string as follows :**

> SUB8&20.000,-&succes&09/12/18SUB12&100.000,-&failed&07/12/18SUB16&40.000,-&succes&09/12/18

**I want to get a string** `"8&20.000","16&40.000"` between `SUB` and `,-&succes`

---

***I want to get `succes data` how to get the string using java regex ?***

Comment: Did you make any attempt to write the regex? Try regex101.com

Comment: You need to better explain what you're looking for.  Here, it seems that you are looking for the success information, but the global structure is not explained.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin thank you, right I mean like that, I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex,

```
SUB([^,]*),-&succes
```

Java code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "SUB8&20.000,-&succes&09/12/18SUB12&100.000,-&failed&07/12/18SUB16&40.000,-&succes&09/12/18";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("SUB([^,]*),-&succes");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Prints,

```
8&20.000
16&40.000
```

**[Check here](https://regex101.com/r/M8FsCF/1)**

Comment: sorry I just updated the question because there is something missing, is this still working on my latest question?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the pattern `SUB[^S]+&success[^S]+` and choose the one you want after that.

The two match would be `SUB8&20.000,-&succes&09/12/18` and `SUB16&40.000,-&succes&09/12/18`.

Once you have chosen you can strip away the unwanted stuff with `[0-9]+&[0-9.]+`.

Answer (score 1):

I don`t know if I am answering your question properly or not. But this regex will give exact string that you are looking for.

```
(?<=SUB)([^,]*)(?=,-&succes)
```

https://regex101.com/r/RLFXNf/1